# Controlling multiple bits flipping to represent chromosomes mutation

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, genetic-algorithm, mutation, genetic-programming

**I am working on an optimization problem. I have `X` number of ambulance locations, where `X` ranges from `1-39`.**

There are `43` numbers [Ambulance Locations] to choose from  `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39)` , we choose `3` of them since I have 3 ambulances.

```
To encode my problem for `programming`, I am working on Chromosome representation:
I can only put my ambulance in three locations among 1-39 locations (Restriction).
```

Assume that I want to put my Ambulance on the `5th, 19th, and 31 positions.`
I am doing something like this for a better presentation:

```
Chromosome 1 = [5, 19, 31] --> 3 Ambulances

Chromosome 1= [000010000000000000100000000000100000000] - Chromosome Presentation
```

In the above presentation, `I am turning on 5-bit, 19-bit, and 31-bit.`

**To achieve mutation, what can be a good way to randomly change present positions to other positions keeping the range only between 1-39 locations (Restriction)?**

Comment: `random.sample(range(1,40),3)`? would give you 3 bit positions at random ... that you could encode with `test_num = sum(1<<i for i in random.sample(range(1,40),3))`  is that what you mean? then you could print it with `f"{test_num:039b}"`

Comment: @JoranBeasley Yes. This is something very close. It is giving me `3` binary number positions among `39 positions`. Since I want to do mutation, I do not want to repeat the sequence of the generated `3 bits`.  I am following this formula `(Combinations without repetition (Is order important: No)` - https://www.hackmath.net/en/calculator/combinations-and-permutations?
n=39&k=3&order=0&repeat=0). 

How can I avoid repetition of the generated 3 bits, keeping order is not important? for instance I want 100 samples of `f"{test_num:039b}"`

Comment: @JoranBeasley This is very interesting. Why are you using 1<<i ? Can you explain it a bit?

Comment: it shifts a 1 that many positions into a string... summing them will give you all 3 ones.. you would need to then keep track of combos that you had seen and just retry .... or get all the combos of 3 number from that list using something like itertools.combinations and just shuffle that and pop items off the top until its empty

Comment: @JoranBeasley Very well. Then, I think the resultant string of 39 bits will always be unique, with no duplicates? For instance, if I `generate 100 or 200` strings using `test_num = sum(1<<i for i in random.sample(range(1,40),3))` . These all will be unique. Am I wrong?

Comment: naw ... you could pick the same 3 random ints... to guarantee uniqueness you would need to create all the combinations of 3 values from that list and then randomly pick them out and remove them from the list ... or keep track of the combo's you have seen and if you get a duplicate pick another set of random 3 ... if you need full exploration this might take a while

Comment: @JoranBeasley Oh I see. Thank you very much for the detailed answer. Since I am using a Genetic Algorithm, I am trying to do a `cross-over` of the resultant 39-bits `(Chromosome 1 000000000000110000000000000100000000000)`, and `Chromosome  2 000000001000100000100000000000000000000)`. However, it seems a bit difficult to perform it. Can you suggest me any intelligent way to do it?

Comment: if you have one candidate with say `A=[1,2,3]` and another that is say `B= [6,7,8]`  to cross polinate you could just say `[random.choice(A),random.choice(B),random.choice(set(range(1,40)).difference(A+B)]` which would pick one index from each parent, and then one random index that is different... you might have to repick from parent B if it happened to share an index

Comment: @JoranBeasley Since my candidate solutions are encoded in `39-bits`. Like I have a `Candidate1 (111000000000000000000000000000000000000)`
`Candidate1 (000000000000000000000000000000000000111)`. How above idea will work according to this encoding?

Comment: that is going to be a painful datastructure to mutate (its good for evaluation probably though) ... i would just do something like  `random.choice([bit1,bit2] for bit1,bit2 in zip(A,B)` and if i ended up with too many ones i would randomly toggle ones off

Comment: @JoranBeasley I absolutely agree with you. I wanted to represent my candidate like A=[1,2,3], and B= [6,7,8]. However, my supervisor wants me to encode it in 39-bits. He believes, it is a standard way of doing.  However, I am stuck with the cross-over part. Can you give me any other solution which can be used to perform cross-over? I will try the above one too. Any other possibility?

Comment: Hi there!

My question is from @JoranBeasley that how this random.choice([bit1,bit2] for bit1,bit2 in zip(A,B) will work for candidate solutions (Shared by @Exploring AI) encoded in 39-bits . Assuming `Candidate solution 1 (111000000000000000000000000000000000000)` and `Candidate Solution 2 (000000000000000000000000000000000000111)`. I am also interested in this. Can you complete this `random.choice([bit1,bit2] for bit1,bit2 in zip(A,B)` for the above two chromosomes?

Comment: for each position in the string it picks randomly from `S1[i],S2[i]` thus providing a child that is formed from the values of the parents... you could easily end up with two many ones in this version so you would need to keep track and if you already have 3 ones, you would just fill the rest with zeros

Comment: @JoranBeasley I have further posted a question where I have explained my problem. Please suggest me something which can help me to optimize my problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73973590/controlling-mutation-in-39bit-string-as-a-candidate-solution-in-genetic-algorith