# Controlling Mutation in 39bit string as a candidate solution in genetic algorithm

Tags: python-2.7, bit-manipulation, genetic-algorithm, mutation, genetic-programming

**I am working on an optimization problem. I have `X` number of ambulance locations, where `X` ranges from `1-39`.**

There are `43` numbers [Ambulance Locations] to choose from  `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39)` , we choose `3` of them since I have 3 ambulances.

I can only put my ambulance in three locations among 1-39 locations (Restriction). Assume that I want to put my Ambulance on the `5th, 19th, and 31 positions.` --  `Chromosome 1= [000010000000000000100000000000100000000]`. In the above presentation, `I am turning on 5-bit, 19-bit, and 31-bit.`

Is it possible to flip a bit close to the original solution? For example, keeping `2 bits` on in the original position and randomly changing the `3rd bit` close to `2bits`. `It is important for me to keep 3bits on among 39bits`. I want to make a control mutation with the aim to produce a small change.

My goal is to `make small changes` since each `bit` represents a `location`. The purpose of mutation is to make small changes and see evaluate results. Therefore, a code should do something like this. `As for CS1:` `(111000000000000000000000000000000000000)`, I want something like `(011010000000000000000000000000000000000)`, or `(011001000000000000000000000000000000000)`, or `(010110000000000000000000000000000000000)` or `(101010000000000000000000000000000000000)`, or `(00101100000000000000000000000000000000)`, etc

**To achieve mutation, what can be a good way to randomly change present positions to other positions keeping the range only between 1-39 locations (Restriction)?**

Comment: Does it specifically have to be somewhere *close* to the original position? Or anywhere?

Comment: @JeremySavage somewhere close to the original position. My `goal` is to `make small changes` since each bit represents a `location`. The purpose of mutation is to make small changes and see evaluate results. Therefore, a code should do something like this. As for `CS1:` `(111000000000000000000000000000000000000)`, I want something like `(011010000000000000000000000000000000000)`, or `(011001000000000000000000000000000000000)`, or
`(010110000000000000000000000000000000000)` or
`(101010000000000000000000000000000000000)`, or
`(00101100000000000000000000000000000000)`, 
etc

Comment: @JeremySavage I updated the question following the above scenario.

Comment: Thanks, @ExploringAI, the whole "being close to the original location" makes it harder to perform, in particular when the bit is in the center of the string. I will have to think about it and see if I can come up with a suitable solution.

Comment: @JeremySavage I have updated the question. I hope it will further help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use numpy and do something like

```
import numpy

s = "1110000000000000000000000000"
def mutate(s):
    arr = numpy.array(list(s))
    mask = arr == "1"
    indices_of_ones = numpy.argwhere(mask).flatten()
    pick_one_1_index = numpy.random.choice(indices_of_ones)
    potential_swaps = numpy.argwhere(~mask).flatten()
    distances = numpy.abs(pick_one_1_index - potential_swaps)
    probabilities = (1/distances) # higher probabilities the less distance from its original position
    # probabilities = (1/(distances*2)) # even higher probabilities the less distance from its original position
    pick_one_0_index = numpy.random.choice(potential_swaps,p=probabilities/probabilities.sum())
    arr[pick_one_1_index] = '0'
    arr[pick_one_0_index] = '1'
    return "".join(arr)
```

there is likely a more optimal solution

alternatively you can add a scalar or power to the distances to penalize more for distance...

if you wanted to test different multipliers or powers for the probabilities
you could use something like

```
def score_solution(s1,s2):
    ix1 = set([i for i,v in enumerate(s1) if v == "1"])
    ix2 = set([i for i,v in enumerate(s2) if v == "1"])
    a,b = ix1 ^ ix2
    return numpy.abs(a-b)

def get_solution_score_quantiles(sample_size=100,quantiles = [0.25,0.5,0.75]):
    scores = []
    for i in range(10):
        s1 = mutate(s)
        scores.append(score_solution(s,s1))
    return numpy.quantile(scores,quantiles)

print(get_solution_score_quantiles(50))
```

Comment: This seems very relevant to what I want. It will take months for me to understand and carry on this logic for my optimization problem since I just started learning. Although I can see some commented code, is it possible if you can add up more comments on the code? It will greatly help me.

Comment: @Joran Beasley After getting the values `[ 4.25  6.5  14.5 ]` from the second code, How can we use them for first code? Can you make another section and post a code and use generated values  `[ 4.25  6.5  14.5 ]` to show its impact on the passed string `s = "1110000000000000000000000000"`.

Comment: Those numbers are showing you average distance of the solution from the starting string...  You wouldn't really use them... You would use the return value from the mutate function

Comment: @JoranBeasley After your code, you quoted `"there is likely a more optimal solution"`. You mean the code your shared can be improved, or it is itself an optimal one?

Comment: i mean the code is likely sub optimal and can be improved with other methods ... but it should work and is probably "fast enough" (but might not be)...

Comment: @JoranBeasley Since I am an absolute beginner and just started my journey to explore AI.  I want to build my understanding following your code. If possible, can you please comment the posted code? It will help me a lot.

Comment: which line is hard to understand? i tried to add comments and use well named variables ...