# Cross-over is failing binary encoded string

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm, mutation, genetic-programming, crossover

I am implementing Genetic Algorithm (GA).
There are `43` numbers [Ambulance Locations] to choose from `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39)` , I choose `3` places since I have `3` ambulances.

I can only put my ambulance in `3` locations among `1-39 locations` **(Restriction)**.

A chromosome sample: `[000010000000000000100000000000100000000]`. This represents that I want to put my Ambulance on the `5th, 19th, and 31 positions.` The bits against positions `5th`, `19th`, and `31` are `1` and rest positions are `0`. In other words, I am turning on `5-bit, 19-bit, and 31-bit`.

Let's say

```
Parent1 (111000000000000000000000000000000000000)
```

and

```
Parent2 (000000000000000000000000000000000000111)
```

After a `cross-over`, I am getting this:

`('111000000000000000000000000000000000111', '000000000000000000000000000000000000000')`

In the first off-spring, I have `six 1's` and in the second off-spring, I have `Zero 1's`. These `generated off-springs` are `illegal` for me since I need off-springs string with `three` `1's` only.

I am using one-point cross-over. This is my code:

```
from typing import Union
import random

Parent 1 ="111000000000000000000000000000000000000"
Parent 2 ="000000000000000000000000000000000000111"


def crossover(cs1: str, cs2: str) -> Union[str, str]:
    index: int = random.randint(0, len(cs1))
    return cs1[:index] + cs2[index:], cs2[:index] + cs1[index:]

crossover(Cs1,Cs2)
```

**What can be a good approach to perform cross-over while keeping`3` bits among `1-39 bits`?**

Comment: what would expect from `000000000000000000000000000000000000111` and `000000000000000000000000000000000000111` (yes same) ?

Comment: @azro Actually, none of them will work since there is no diversity in these off-springs. I need something which will help to explore my search space in a smart way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you want to mix the two parents randomly, keeping exactly 3 '1's?

You can get the indices of the 1s in each parent and select them randomly:

```
import random

Parent1 ="111000000000000000000000000000000000000"
Parent2 ="000000000000000000000000000000000000111"

def indices(s):
    return {i for i,c in enumerate(s) if c=='1'}

def crossover(p1, p2, k=3):

    idx = set(random.sample(list(indices(p1) | indices(p2)), k=k))

    return ''.join('1' if i in idx else '0' for i in range(len(p1)))

out = crossover(Parent1, Parent2, k=Parent1.count('1'))
# '110000000000000000000000000000000000100'
```

If you want to give more weight to a position that is 1 in both strings, you can modify the above to use a `Counter` in place of a set:

```
import random
from collections import Counter

Parent1 ="111000000000000000000000000000000000000"
Parent2 ="000000000000000000000000000000000000111"

def indices(s):
    return Counter(i for i,c in enumerate(s) if c=='1')

def crossover(p1, p2, k=3):

    # count the number of 1 per position
    pool = indices(p1) | indices(p2)
    
    # randomly select indices
    # using the counts as weights
    idx = set(random.sample(list(pool),
                            counts=pool.values(),
                            k=k))

    return ''.join('1' if i in idx else '0' for i in range(len(p1)))

out = crossover(Parent1, Parent2, k=Parent1.count('1'))
# '010000000000000000000000000000000000101'
```

##### shuffle the bits between two offsprings:

using set operations

```
import random

def indices(s):
    return {i for i,c in enumerate(s) if c=='1'}

def crossover(p1, p2):
    # get positions of 1s for each string
    idx1 = indices(p1)
    idx2 = indices(p2)
    
    # positions that are different in both strings
    differ = idx1.symmetric_difference(idx2)
    # identical positions
    common = idx1&idx2
    
    # pick half of the different positions randomly
    select = set(random.sample(list(differ), k=len(differ)//2))
    
    # offspring 1 get those positions + the common ones
    select1 = select | common
    # offstring 2 gets the other positions + the common ones
    select2 = (differ-select) | common
    
    # make strings from the selected positions for each offspring
    out1 = ''.join('1' if i in select1 else '0' for i in range(len(p1)))
    out2 = ''.join('1' if i in select2 else '0' for i in range(len(p1)))
    
    return out1, out2
    
crossover(Parent1, Parent2)
```

example output:

```
('101000000000000000000000000000000000001',
 '010000000000000000000000000000000000110')
```

Comment: This seems very reasonable. a very smart way. However, I need two off-springs to carry on. Following this solution, how can we get two off-spring?

Comment: Are the two offsprings independent? exclusive in terms of bits?

Comment: Usually, when we do a cross-over from two parents, we get two off-springs. If we take these parents, `Parent1 ="111000000000000000000000000000000000000"`
`Parent2 ="000000000000000000000000000000000000111"`. Following your solution, we are getting `1 off-spring` which is `'010000000000000000000000000000000000101'`. Is it possible to get `two off-springs` following the same logic or criteria? Do you get my point?

Comment: check the update for complementary offsprings

Comment: I think it will take months to understand this logic :D. Can you do me a favor by commenting on the code? It will help to understand in carrying the concept for my optimization problem.

Comment: Here are the comments ;)

Comment: Thanks a ton. I can debug and make my understanding. I am also keeping your second code which included a counter as a weight.  Can you make comments on that too? Last favor :D

Comment: @mozway This is good stuff.  I am also interested in the second code solution "give more weight to a position that is 1 in both strings, you can modify the above to use a Counter in place of a set". Can you please add comments to the code?

Comment: @ExploringAI it's quite simple, you counts the positions with 1 for both strings and use those counts as weights in `random.sample`. Thus if a position has 1 in both strings you have twice as many chances to select this position. You could generalize this approach to n strings.

Comment: @mozway I got my confusion clear. I am using similar encoded data in a question but dealing with mutation. If possible, please have a look (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73973590/controlling-mutation-in-39bit-string-as-a-candidate-solution-in-genetic-algorith).  Do have any good idea to do mutation?

Comment: @mozway I have updated my question to increase problem understanding. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73973590/controlling-mutation-in-39bit-string-as-a-candidate-solution-in-genetic-algorith

Comment: @mozway is it `One Point Crossover, Multi Point Crossover, or Uniform Crossover`?

Comment: I think it is a variation of `One Point Crossover`? @mozway

Comment: @Oceans I don't know the terminology. I would say it's similar to a multiple crossover

Comment: @mozway according to your solution, **shuffle the bits between two offsprings:** If we pass the value `Parent1 ="010000000000000000000000000000000000101"`
`Parent2 ="110000000000000000000000000000000000100"`, the off-spring values will be exactly similar to the parents.  i-e `Child-1:110000000000000000000000000000000000100` 
 `Child-2:010000000000000000000000000000000000101`. Can you have a look?

Comment: This is a problem in this solution. It will happen as #mozway is mixing the two parents randomly (not a good solution). However, in a better solution, we need to do a cross-over upon the values according to the parents to generate offsprings. I think @mozway can make slight changes to get it.